# Where does this equation come from?

Tags: fluid-dynamics, velocity, drag, speed, viscosity

I am investigating about viscosity of fluids and I found the following equation to calculate the viscosity:
$$\nu = \frac{2(\rho_s-\rho_l)\cdot g \cdot r^{2}}{9\cdot\Delta v} $$

The experiment consists of having a tube with whatever liquid you would like to measure and drop a ball and see at which speed it reaches the bottom.

$\rho_s$ is the density of the sphere, $\rho_l$ the density of the liquid, $g$ the acceleration of gravity, $v$ the final velocity and $r$ is the radius of the ball.

The problem is, I really do not know where this equation comes from nor do I know if it is correct.

Comment: Sounds like a job for Stokes' law.

Comment: This comes from applying Stokes law and Archemides principal to determine the terminal velocity of a sphere falling through a fluid.